# Closed questions

Tags: discussion, closed-questions

Once a question is closed, shouldn't any comments also be closed? The ["is there a way to design a realistic religion"](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/824/is-there-an-effective-way-to-design-a-realistic-religion-for-a-world) question is turning into a debate forum completely inappropriate to SE.

Comment: It doesn't matter that the question was closed. That discussion should have been migrated to chat.

Comment: I agree. It's not a proper use of SE to debate opinions.

Answer (score 7):

No, comments should not be closed. This is because questions being closed is a temporary measure. If and when the question has had the problems with it fixed (if that is possible) then it can be opened and the comments are a vital part of that process.

If there is specific abuse of comments happening in one question then that should be dealt with there. Looking at the question though I only see 4 or 5 new comments in the last day, not enough to worry about yet although it would be better taken to chat and if the number of comments does explode a moderator will most likely step in and enforce that.

Comment: The question was closed as too broad. If your reasoning is correct, comments not specifically aimed toward narrowing the question should be flagged as inappropriate. Yes?

Comment: @CAgrippa Why? The comments pointed out reasons why the question should be closed, which could be useful in the future. There was no debate. I agree that chat was a possibility, though.